# Python lambda: Assign function to another function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I have two functions, which I would like to combine:
The first function called f(rdata, t) reads in the data for the time horizont t and arranges it for further modelling

```
def f(rdata,t):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(rdata, sep = ",", skiprows = 3)
    data = dataset.loc[:,dataset.dtypes == np.float64] 
    data = pd.concat([dataset.OS_TERM, data], axis = 1).set_index(dataset.SIMULATION)
    rdata = data.loc[data["OS_TERM"] == t ].drop("OS_TERM", axis = 1).T.add_prefix("Sim_")
    return(rdata)
```

The second function quantile(data, q, n, ascending) calculates a hypothetical quantile q and compares it to the outcome of the first function, showing the n most extreme observations

```
def quantile(data, q , n , ascending):
    name =  str(q)
    quant = pd.DataFrame({name:data.quantile(q, axis = 1)})
    quant_dif = pd.DataFrame(data.values - quant.values, columns = data.columns)**2
    cum_dif = pd.DataFrame(quant_dif.sum(axis = 0), columns = ["cum_dif"])
    out = pd.DataFrame(cum_dif.sort(["cum_dif"], ascending = ascending).ix[0:n,:])
    index = out.index.values
    sims = pd.DataFrame(data.loc[:, index])
    return(sims)
```

To combine the two I could built the following function

```
quantile(f(rdata), t), q, n, ascending)
```

Nevertheless I would like to create a function, which reads in the data for a time horizon t, and then applies the quantile in a second step

```
f(data, t, quantile(data, q, n, ascending))
```

Any suggestions how to set this up, maybe with a Lambda function?

Comment: What's wrong with `quantile(f(rdata), t), q, n, ascending)` actually ?  It does exactly what you're asking for: "reads in the data for a time horizon t, and then applies the quantile in a second step".

Comment: I'd like to read in the data in a first step, and then have the possibility to assign any other function to the data e.g. for the mean                               f(data,t, mean(data))

Comment: if you really need it then `f(data, t, lambda x:quantile(x, q, n, ascending))` and `def f(rdata,t, fun): ... fun(rdata)`

Comment: @Carmen I still fail to understand the problem - if you want to apply another function to the data, then just call this function with the data. Perhaps you could tell more about your concrete use case  cause it really looks like a XY problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing things in the most convoluted way, you could use a `partial` as callback:

```
from functools import partial

def apply(rdata, t, callback):
    data = f(rdata, t)
    return callback(data=data)


apply(rdata, t, partial(qantile, q=q, n=n, ascending=ascending))
```

or with a lambda:

```
apply(
   rdata, t, 
   lambda data, q=q, n=n, asc=ascending: qantile(data, q, n, asc)
   )
```

But in both cases I fail to see how it's an improvement over the plain and obvious solution...